# How to write a for-loop to read 1000 text files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have 1000 text files that their names are A0000.txt, A0001.text, ..., A1000.text.
I want to read in the information in the text files and store some of them in an excel file or a csv file (csv is preferred).

How should I define a for loop that can do this task?

I can use this function `A = textread('A0000.txt','%s')` to read one text file, but I don't know how should I put it in a for loop. If the name of the files were 1.txt, 2.txt,..., 1000.txt it would be easier.

I would be thankful if you can provide any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `sprintf` to generate the relevant strings:

```
for i=1:1000
    fileName = sprintf('A%04d.txt',i);
    A{i} = textread(fileName ,'%s')
end
```

The `%04d` tells `sprintf` that the number should have leading zeroes.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working! 
There is just a typo : `sprintf('A%04d.txt',i)`

Answer (score 3):

The following generates a list of txt files contained in the current directory. It then reads in all the files. This is useful if the file names are not sequential.

```
filelist = dir([pwd() filesep '*.txt' ]);
fileNames = {filelist.name}';
nFiles = length(fileNames);

for i= 1:nFiles 
    TF{i} = textread(fileNames{i},'%s');  
end
```